# Grails: Pre-select a g:select option in a table row using g:each

Tags: grails

I'm having an issue with preselecting an entry in a grails select drop down. I have a table and each row has a drop down.

The rows in the table are defined by a g:each:

```
<g:each in="${fooList}" status="i" var="fooInstance">
```

So this each row has fields of this object, lets just call it Foo!

```
String name
String age
Bar xyz
```

The problem comes in the last column. The object has within it another object (Bar xyz). I want to be able to change this Bar (which is a domain object) in the current Foo. But the Foo may already have a Bar in it when the page loads.

How do I tie the select to the pre-populated sub-object? The select has within it the possible values of the sub object (All Bars currently available) but the binding isn't working!

```
<td>${fieldValue(bean: fooInstance, field: "name")}</td> //this is fine

<td><g:select from="${Bar.list()}" name="xyz" 
optionValue="${fooInstance.xyz}" value="${fooInstance.xyz.id}" 
optionKey="id" noSelection="['':'-Choose a Bar-']" /></td>
```

Any ideas? Hope that's clear enough, let me know if you need any other info,

Thanks,
Tony

By the way, the stack trace I get is:

> Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: xxxxxxxxx.Bar.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (xxxxxxx.Bar) values: [aaablahblah]
>   Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), getAll(), getId(), getAll([Ljava.lang.Long;), getAll(java.util.List), get(java.io.Serializable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for the select tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html), the `optionValue` should be the property of the current item that is displayed in the body of the `Select` ie `optionValue="${{it.someProperty}}"` where `it` is the `Bar` that is being displayed.

Does that work?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for replying. I changed the value property and I don't get the error above anymore, but at the same time the select drop-downs are not prepopulated. In other words the screen loads but the databinding is not taking place. The noSelection value is displayed. Do you se an error with my syntax by any chance? I took away the optionValue entry too cos I'm not sure what it was doing. '<td><g:select from="${Bar.list()}" name="xyz" value="${fooInstance.xyz}" optionKey="id" noSelection="['':'-Choose an Analyst-']" /></td>'

Comment: try setting `optionValue` to be the property of `Bar` that you want displayed in the body of the `Select` eg `optionValue="${{it.title}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get a `missingMethodException`, I find that I need to stop the server, clean the project, and then restart the server.

Comment: Thanks for replying Universitas, but unfortunately I still get the error after a full clean and restart. Cheers for the suggestion, though.